Select script in specific table having large data responding too slow, even delete duplicates not working
I want to delete rows having duplicate TBO_code so i can use it as unique key, but when i run the below Delete query, it gives 504 error after take loading of almost 30minutes
DELETE QUERY*
DELETE t1 FROM TBO_hotels t1
  JOIN TBO_hotels t2
  ON t2.TBO_code = t1.TBO_code
  AND t2.id < t1.id

I have also tried to use LIMIT to check may be with smaller data it working, but with below query it gives Syntax Error
QUERY WITH LIMIT
DELETE t1 FROM `TBO_hotels` t1
      JOIN `TBO_hotels` t2
      ON t2.TBO_code = t1.TBO_code
      AND t2.id < t1.id LIMIT 1000


Please only ask one question in a post. Please clarify if you use mysql or mariadb. The two are not the same.

being picky are wp_TBO_hotels and CREATE TABLE TBO_hotels the same thing?

Does this answer your question? MySQL delete duplicate records but keep latest

What is wp_TBO_hotels ? Another table? Is there index on wp_TBO_hotels (TBO_code)?

answered your first question; create a separate question for your slow select question (including output of show create table, not your separate create and alter table statements, and output of explain select...)

@P.Salmon
i just missed to remove wp_ however its same

@ValNik
it is just a mistake while writing question on stack overflow

@Shadow
thank you let me break my query into 2

@ysth
done this

The LIMIT clause is only available for the single table form of delete.
But you can use an EXISTS condition instead of a join:
delete from wp_TBO_hotels
where exists (
    select 1
    from wp_TBO_hotels t2
    where t2.id < wp_TBO_hotels.id and t2.TBO_code=wp_TBO_hotels.TBO_code
)
limit 1000

fiddle
